# Display flex in IE10 with non block children doesn't work correctly

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, flexbox

I've run into an inconsistency in IE 10 support and flexbox.

See this code pen: http://codepen.io/davestaab/pen/mywbxd
or this snippet:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: #555555;
}

.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  padding: 15px;
  border-top: thin solid black;
  border-bottom: thin solid black;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  
}

.flex-child {
  flex: 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.flex-child-label {
  flex: 1;
  /* have to add this to get it to work correctly in IE10 */
  /*display:block;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-parent">
    <span class="flex-child-label">Inbox</span>
    <span class="flex-child">1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-parent">
    <span class="flex-child-label">Sent</span>
    <span class="flex-child">2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-parent">
    <span class="flex-child-label">More</span>
    <span class="flex-child">3</span>
  </div>
<div>
```

Here's the css in question:

```
.flex-child-label {
  flex: 1;
  /* have to add this to get it to work correctly in IE10 */
  /*display:block;*/
}
```

This works as expected in webkit browsers and IE11. In IE10 however the flex:1; style on the .flex-child-label class seems to be ignored. If i make the .flex-child-label class be display:block it works as expected.

Is it just a fact that I need to make sure children of flexbox are display block? Is there a -ms- class/property I should be using? Is this a bug in IE10 or is this part of the older flexbox spec?

Thanks

Comment: I've heard that IE10 uses the 2012 spec (just the previous one), but AFAIK the concept of flex items being laid out as blocks (row) or inline-blocks (column) didn't change between then and now.

Comment: The default value of a span is inline.   Since they are inline by default, their width is smaller than if they were block and flexbox will calculate the width via flex-grow differently.

Comment: The SO post above answers my question. Great find. So what happens now? Should this question be closed somehow? If anyone wants to answer with the above link I'll accept it. Thanks for the help.